# when in Mixradio there is no option to purchasing nokia music

Tags: lumia

Have logged on to Mixradio using Windowsphone password but still do not have the option to buy music

Comment: Do you live in [one of the countries](http://www.mixrad.io/storeselector/countries) where MixRadio is supported?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am not sure but in South Africa Xbox music is not supported. I used Nokiatunes successfully before it was discontinued. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Hi Indrek, I do live in a country where Mixradio is supported. All the functions are available except the option to purchase music. Your comment?